# Loop and Constant in Assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, constants

I just want to ask a question.

How can I display an output like this "**0_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9**"

And I need to use a loop in the numbers, but how can I make *underscore* constant in every loop?

Here is my working codes.

```
.model small

.stack 200h

.code

main proc

    mov ah, 0      
    mov al, 12h   ; Clear screen
    int 10h

    mov ah,3    
    mov bh,0     ; get cursor
    int 10h

    mov ah,2      
    mov bh,0      ;set cursor
    mov dl,12
    int 10h


    mov cx, 9     ; counter

    Mov ah, 2
    Mov dl, 48     ; display 0  
top:

    int 21h

    add dl, 47      ; display underscore
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    push dx

    add dl, -46     ; return to 1
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    pop dx



loop top    

    mov ah, 4ch
    mov al,00h
    int 21h


endp

end main
```

I always result in this, please click [here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/d9x5.jpg/)

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: This should get you started. http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_161.html If you need to lookup other instructions you here is the index: http://x86.renejeschke.de/

Answer (score 3):

This is relative to the current digit, which will give you incorrect results for anything except when the digit is `'0'`:

```
add dl, 47      ; display underscore
mov ah, 2
int 21h
```

You're also pushing and popping `dx` in the wrong places (relative to where you're changing its value).

A better approach would be:

```
top:
int 21h         ; print digit

push dx         ; save dx 

mov dl,'_'
mov ah, 2
int 21h         ; print underscore

pop dx          ; restore dx
inc dl          ; next digit
loop top
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works fine:

```
; 0_9.asm
; assemble with "nasm -f bin -o 0_9.com 0_9.asm"

    org  0x100        ; .com files always start 256 bytes into the segment

    mov cx, 9     ; counter
    mov dl, "0" ; 0

top:
    push dx
    push cx
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    mov dl, "_"      ; display underscore
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    pop cx
    pop dx
    inc dl
loop top  

    mov dl, "9"      ; display 9
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h


    mov ah, 4ch     ; "terminate program" sub-function
    mov al,00h
    int 21h
```